# Executing custom mysql query and "Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

im 'newbie' in Symfony :)
Im trying to execute this sql:

```
SELECT cat.name, ri.category_id,AVG(ri.value) as avarage FROM company c
JOIN reviews r ON r.company_id = c.id
JOIN reviews_items ri ON ri.review_id = r.id
JOIN category cat ON ri.category_id = cat.id
WHERE c.id = 1
GROUP BY ri.category_id
```

in Symfony2 doctrine by:

```
$cats = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT cat.name, ri.category, AVG(ri.value),r as avarage 
            FROM DiligesDiligesBundle:Company c
            JOIN c.reviews r
            JOIN r.reviews ri
            JOIN ri.category cat
            WHERE c.id = 1
            GROUP BY ri.category'
        )->getResult();
```

But it gives me an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 20 near 'category, AVG(ri.value),r': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Don't know why, can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Ive changed SELECTed items toto:

```
'SELECT c,r,ri,cat.name,AVG(ri.value) as avarage
```

and I dont get error but I get wrong item (only one - it should be 4 of them). I need select just selected columns of tables, not all of them.

*PS. Sorry if my language (english) is not so good :D*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you can cast custom SQL directly inside the query builder this way.

The method I use is as follow :

```
public Function myCustomQuery() {
    $sql = 
    <<<EOF
        MY_SQL_CODE_HERE
    EOF
    ;

    $myQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $myQuery->execute();
    $result = $myQuery->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query looks fine, however, you won't be able to call `getResult()` because it's not the entity you're trying to retrieve.

Try using `getArrayResult()` instead...

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem probably:

```
r as avarage
```

I am not sure  what do u want to get there but I guess it should be just `r` (all columns from table) or `r.column_name as avarage` because `r` is alias for table already

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be:
    'cat.name, ri.category, AVG(ri.value) as avarage, r'
but it still dont change anything.